# If a quotation makes up all of a person's speech does it still need to be in its own quote marks?

Tags: style, dialogue, quotes, chicago-manual-of-style

I have the following speech in a book I'm designing:

> Seeing him hesitate, she said lightly, ‘“‘There’s both meat and music here,’ quoth the dog as he ate the piper’s bag”!’

Essentially someone is quoting a phrase in which there is also speech.

Are the three sets of quotation marks necessary or, if a quote makes up all of a person's speech, can it just be enclosed in their speech marks? As so:

> Seeing him hesitate, she said lightly, ‘“There’s both meat and music here,” quoth the dog as he ate the piper’s bag!’

Answer (score 0):

Dialogue is the written representation of spoken language. Like a transcript of an audio recording. **You cannot speak quotation marks**, so don't use them within dialogue. Instead employ the following or similar methods:

1. Let your characters *state* that they read or heard what they say somewhere or from someone:

   > John said: "Yesterday Peter said, and I quote: I won't come to Olivia's party."
2. Show that they *change their voice:*

   > John said: "I met Peter and he said: *I won't come to Olivia's party!*" John mimicked Peter's voice and Olivia giggled.
3. Describe how they make *gestures* such as quotation marks with their fingers:

   > "Do you think Peter will come?" Olivia asked?
   >      "I don't think so," Peter replied. He made quotation marks with his fingers: "I won't come to Olivia's party."
   >      Olivia looked crestfallen.
4. If *the listener is familiar with the quotation*, you don't need to point it out in any way:

   > Father looked at John sternly: "Thou shalt not take the name of the Lord thy God in vain!"

The only markup that is conventionally used within dialogue in fiction is italics. It is commonly used for emphasis (that is, when people put stress on a word) or changes of voice (for example, when they speak louder or in a different voice).

Some works of fiction use nested quotes. To me, as a reader, this feels jarring and wrong, because that usage fails to take into account what dialogue is: spoken language.

Here is a real world example from chapter five of *The Holy Machine* by Chris Beckett, where one speaker cites the speech of another:

> ‘Oh George, where have you been? I wish you'd *say* when you're going to be late. I needed you here. It's Shirley! Someone's coming round to see us. I'm going out of my mind with worry...’
>      ‘What do you mean, it's Shirley?’ I asked her.

As you can see the quotation "it's Shirley" isn't in nested quotation marks or marked up in any other way, because dialogue in fiction is a representation of spoken language and **you cannot speak quotation marks**.

---

This is different in non-fiction, where quotations can be nested because what you quote is *written* language:

> Peters (1998) wrote: "Willams (1856) wrote: 'Brown (1744) wrote: "Something." ' "

I would avould this, though, as it can be confusing.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have just found this in CMS as an example of correct useage:

“Don’t be absurd!” said Henry. “To say that‚ ‘I mean what I say’ is the same as‚ ‘I say what I mean’ is to be as confused as Alice at the Mad Hatter’s tea party. You remember what the Hatter said to her: ‘Not the same thing a bit! Why you might just as well say that “I see what I eat” is the same thing as “I eat what I see”!’”

Comment: I don't know of any style guide that makes different recommendations depending on the fictitiousness of the work. In my experience, nested quotes in fiction are utterly common. They make it so the author does not have to explicitly describe the change of tone or gesture that would clearly and intuitively delineate the quoted words in spoken dialogue. There's no need to include text explaining what the punctuation already accomplishes more efficiently.

Comment: @Ben The same way I indicate I'm quoting someone when speaking in any other scenario - with a slight pause, a change in tone, or by providing context.

Comment: @DanielJamesSmith That example from the CMS is expicitly an example about how to use quotation marks ***if*** you nest quotes. Nowhere in the CMS do its authors state that you *should* use nested quotes in fiction!

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes can probably be divided into two groups: one you expect all the characters and readers to recognize, and those you don't.

For the first, you can just have the character say them. In the case of a quote that contains a quote, a paraphrase or allusion might be the way to go.

> She grinned. "Reminds me of that saying about the dog who ate a piper's bag and declared there was both meat and music there!"

After all, few of us actually literally just quote stuff at each other. It's more natural to refer to it, unless it's a rule or a commandment or something, or super famous.

> She grinned. "Neither a borrower nor a lender be, eh?"

For the second, you can have the character use just the nested quote, then elaborate with the rest.

> She grinned. "A case of 'both meat and music here' is it?"

> He frowned. "What?"

> "You know, FamousWork, 'quoth the dog as he ate the piper’s bag', right?"

Here you have quotes in quotes but at least it's not triply nested, and you're explaining the source.

I do think it's worth a little gymnastics to keep from butting up your quote marks against each other. The "is it" serves mostly that purpose in the first sentence of my last example.